# How to bubble sort array of pointers to the another array of chars

Tags: c++, pointers, char, bubble-sort

I have one array containing `chars` from the input and the other array containing pointers to the corresponding `chars` in the first array. This part went good.

But then I would like to bubble sort the `char**` array (array of pointers)  so the original array stays untouched but something goes wrong(the text is not sorted).

```
EDIT: Please discuss only the sorting algorithm


 char tab[200];//array of chars 
 char** t = new char*[tabLength];
 //SOMETHING
....

....
int n = tabLength;//length of tab(length of the word it contains)
//TILL HERE EVERYTHING IS FINE -----------------------------------
         //bubble sorting below
do{
    for(int i = 0; i < n -1; i++){
        if(*t[i] > *t[i+1]){
            char* x = t[i];
            t[i] = t[i+1];
            t[i+1] = x;
        }
        n--;
    }
}while(n>1);

cout<<"sorted input";
for(int i = 0; i < tabLength; i++)
    cout<<t[i];
    cout<<endl;

cout<<"original"<<tab<<endl;
```

Comment: Is each entry meant to be a C string, or a single char?

Comment: Why do you calculate the length yourself? Why do you even use C-style string instead of `std::string`? If you did use `std::string`, then you could just copy the string and then use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) to sort it.

Comment: @NPE I think he's trying to sort the letters in a C-style string. But instead of actually modifying the array, he's reordering pointers into that array.

Comment: @sftrabbit YES, exacly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you print out the values that the pointers point at:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tabLength; i++)
  cout << *t[i];
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you look at the edit I cut off the code so there is only the sorting algorithm visible. I would like to sort only `t` array (sort pointers).

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use the functionality already at my disposal in the standard library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string original;
    std::getline(std::cin, original);

    std::cout << '|' << original << "|\n";

    std::string sorted = original;
    std::sort(std::begin(sorted), std::end(sorted));

    std::cout << "Sorted  : " << sorted << '\n';
    std::cout << "Original: " << original << '\n';
}
```

Test run:

```
|Hello world, how are you doing today?|
Sorted  :       ,?Haadddeeghilllnoooooorrtuwwyy
Original: Hello world, how are you doing today?
```

Comment: Because I try to understand how to sort array of pointers to other array elements(chars not strings).